# Fix mismatching x-ticks

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I currently have two Pandas DataFrames that I would like to layer on top of another.

```
# Creating plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[16, 9])

ax.scatter(italy_df.columns, italy_df.loc['Record high °C'], label = 'Record high °C', color = '#FF0000') 
ax.scatter(italy_df.columns, italy_df.loc['Record low °C'], label = 'Record low °C', color = '#006BD1')
ax.plot(italy_df.columns, italy_df.loc['Daily mean °C'], label = 'Daily mean °C', color='#2F4858')

# Setting red fill between max and min scatter
ax.fill_between(range(len(italy_df.T.index)),
                 italy_df.loc['Record high °C'], italy_df.loc['Daily mean °C'],
                 facecolor='#FF0000', alpha=0.1, interpolate=False)

# Setting blue fill between min scatter and the min scatter
ax.fill_between(range(len(italy_df.T.index)),
                 italy_df.loc['Daily mean °C'], italy_df.loc['Record low °C'],
                 facecolor='#006BD1', alpha=0.1, interpolate=False)
locations = np.arange(0, 12)
labels = pd.date_range('2020-01-01', '2020-12-31', freq='MS').month_name()
plt.xticks(locations, labels, rotation=45)

ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(covid_positive_2020)
locations = np.arange(0, 305, 30)
labels = pd.date_range('2020-02-01', covid_positive_2020.index.max(), freq='MS').month_name()

plt.show()
```

The following code produces this output:

[image]

As you may see there is a mismatch of xticks. `covid_positive_2020` DataFrame has dates ranging from February to December, whereas my `italy_df` plots an average temperature from January to February.

What I'm trying to achieve is combine both plots where the `covid_positive_2020` would start from February and expand till end of December.

Thank you in advance!

The final result would look something like this:

[image]

Comment: If we want the x-axis to be monthly, we need to group 'covid_positive_2020' by month.

Comment: The issue is that after that I will loose the exact daily data, by groupby and agg function. I'd like to maintain the accuracy of the information.

Comment: I can maintain the time series of the original data if you add the month names to a new column and group them together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an option to achieve my desired result:

Using `ax.twiny().twinx()` I was able to create a secondary x and y axis, on top of which I started plotting.

```
# Creating plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[16, 9])

ticks = np.arange(0, 366)
plt.xticks(ticks)

x = pd.to_datetime(covid_positive_2020.index.min()) 
y = pd.date_range('01/01/2020', x)

ln1 = ax.plot(np.arange(len(y)-1, 366), covid_positive_2020, label='COVID cases 2020', color='darkorange')
ln2 = ax.plot(covid_positive_2021, label='COVID cases 2021', color='purple')

ax.set_ylabel('Number of new cases')
plt.gca().axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)


ax2 = ax.twiny().twinx()

ax2.scatter(italy_df.columns, italy_df.loc['Record high °C'], label = 'Record high °C', color = '#FF0000') 
ax2.scatter(italy_df.columns, italy_df.loc['Record low °C'], label = 'Record low °C', color = '#006BD1')
ln3 = ax2.plot(italy_df.columns, italy_df.loc['Daily mean °C'], label = 'Daily mean °C', color='#2F4858')
ax2.set_ylabel('Temperature $^{\circ}$C')

# Setting red fill between max and min scatter
ax2.fill_between(range(len(italy_df.T.index)),
                 italy_df.loc['Record high °C'], italy_df.loc['Daily mean °C'],
                 facecolor='#FF0000', alpha=0.1, interpolate=False)

# Setting blue fill between min scatter and the min scatter
ax2.fill_between(range(len(italy_df.T.index)),
                 italy_df.loc['Daily mean °C'], italy_df.loc['Record low °C'],
                 facecolor='#006BD1', alpha=0.1, interpolate=False)
locations = np.arange(0, 12)
labels = pd.date_range('2020-01-01', '2020-12-31', freq='MS').month_name()
plt.xticks(locations, labels, rotation=45)
ax2 = plt.gca()

lns = ln1 + ln2 + ln3
legends = [l.get_label() for l in lns]
ax2.legend(lns, legends, loc=0)

plt.rcParams["axes.grid"] = False

plt.show()
```

[image]